# Is there a way to line up select options horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

Like the title says, is there a way to do this? Look at the picture below. The list of tags, displayed horizonatally and overflowing vertically is actually a `div` with a `ul` tag and the `li` tags floated. I'd like to do a similar thing but with a `<select multiple>` box, so the user can select multiple tags before filtering. I've done some google searches on this and haven't found much.

If there is a library that does something similar or some kind of alternative, that would be appreciated also.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Tags image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works -- I just used the long list like from the top example, but instead of using a select tag with options, I just used a series of checkboxes nested within the `li` tags.

With some css work the result looks like this, which I happy with:

[image: Tags New]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using several `<select multiple>` elements, styled so that they all appear to form a single element:

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid rgb(127,127,127);
}

div select {
display: inline-block;
width: 160px;
padding: 24px 6px;
margin: -12px -36px 12px 12px;
border: none;
}

option {
height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
<select multiple data-range="options-1-5">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>
<option>Option 5</option>
</select>

<select multiple data-range="options-6-10">
<option>Option 6</option>
<option>Option 7</option>
<option>Option 8</option>
<option>Option 9</option>
<option>Option 10</option>
</select>

<select multiple data-range="options-11-15">
<option>Option 11</option>
<option>Option 12</option>
<option>Option 13</option>
<option>Option 14</option>
<option>Option 15</option>
</select>

<select multiple data-range="options-16-20">
<option>Option 16</option>
<option>Option 17</option>
<option>Option 18</option>
<option>Option 19</option>
<option>Option 20</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out select2 plugin. This should have what you want for multiple select options. It displays the multiple options as tags. All you need to do is some css work on how it displays those tags and you could make it look the exact same way.

The link to the plugins is:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html